# How to hide a color dialog in windows forms?

Tags: c#

i want to hide the color dialog from the button i defined it in picture box ,i want the button to preform only the if condition

```
 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog colorPicker = new ColorDialog();
        if (colorPicker.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

        }
       

    }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog colorPicker = new ColorDialog();
        if (colorPicker.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

        
                label1.ForeColor = colorPicker.Color;
                pictureBox1.BackColor = colorPicker.Color;

                Color backcolor = Color.FromArgb(colorPicker.Color.ToArgb() ^ 0xffffff);
                this.BackColor = backcolor;
        }
            
      
        
    }
```

Comment: If you do not want the `ColorDialog` to display when the user clicks the picture box… then remove the code that displays the `ColorDialog`.

Comment: no i want it to display in picture box i don't want it in to display when i click the button

Comment: I must be missing something. In the posted code, the `ColorDialog` will display if the user clicks the picture box AND it will display if the user clicks the button. Remove the code from the event you do not want it in. I can only assume there is more to this than you are providing.

Comment: what i want to do is when the user clicks the picture box the color dialog will open and he will chose the color bu without any change occurring in the form and when he clicks the ok button the code in if statement will be preformed

Comment: Well... then in the picture box click event you need to “save” whatever color the user picked. Then when the user clicks the button, DO NOT show the color dialog again and simply use the color that was previously saved. This seems like an odd thing to do, and not very user friendly, but go for it.

Comment: it didn't work i don't know how to figure it out

Comment: Well… you need to [edit] your question and show your updated code. Didn’t work could mean many things. We are forced to guess what your code is doing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when i click on the button the color dialog appears i don't want it to be shown i want to when i click the button the label and the back color will change with the color the user selected from the picture box